# How to put Price on the Right side of Column in DataGridView? (c#.net core) Tiny Problem

Tags: c#, winforms

So apparently it looks better if you have the Price of a Product on the right side inside of a Column like this:

Ofcourse this is an OrderID but the look should be the same.

[image: Here you can see the Number is on the Right side.]

But at the moment mine looks more like this.

[image: Picture of my current Column]

Thanks for helping; C ya!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup each column for the DataGridView in the designer by clicking the chevron

[image]

Select `edit columns` and select the column to set the alignment then select DefaultCellStyle and set alignment to MiddleRight.

Example using mocked data (works the same from a database table). All numeric columns have MiddleRight alignment below.

```
private void OnShown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Item", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Qty", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(decimal));
    table.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(decimal));

    table.Columns["Total"].Expression = "Qty * Price";

    table.Rows.Add("First item", 2, 60);
    table.Rows.Add("Second item", 2, 50);
    table.Rows.Add("Third item", 1, 20);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

}
```

[image]

Manually setting up alignment.

```
var dataGridViewCellStyle1 = new DataGridViewCellStyle { Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight };
PriceColumn.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
```

Comment: I just noticed that I manually added the Collums with code and now they dont Show up when i hit the Edit Collumn button.

Comment: See the last code sample in my response for manually setting up alignment.